# how to select different content from 2 different tables based on same id

Tags: mysql

have 2 tables request and collected. "request" has info when the request id date name, lastname and loan_id.

"collected" has name, last name, collected id, loan_id(equal as loan_id from request) collected date.

my code

```
select * from request inner join collected on request.loan_id = collected.loan_id

Where request.user_id = $userid
```

this output all info from both tables accurately . but i need is it to display from request table all info and from collected just 3 info, as well this will be from 1 to more.

request has 1 loan_id for each request, collected table loan_id repeat multiple times with different data.

result expected request table output name, last name, etc.  collected table amount, date,confirmation. it will be request 1 row per id and collected multiples row for the same loan_id

Comment: @scaisEdge  scaisEdge

Comment: Please update your question  adding  a real data sample  and the expected  result (not only an explanation of the result beacuse the question is not clear to me)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT request.*, collected.column1, collected.column2
FROM request, collected
WHERE request.loan_id = collected.loan_id
AND request.user_id = $userid
```

would work here

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax that is what i got

Comment: Forgot to mention which tables to select from